# currency converter virtuemart

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have one serious problem about configuration auto update exchange rate in ECBconverter

I'm Vietnamese and I want to add Vietnamese Dong rate to Currency converter.
I use file XML from Joint Stock Commercial Bank for Foreign Trade of Vietnam (Vietcombank) to convert EUR to VND
http://www.vietcombank.com.vn/ExchangeRates/ExrateXML.aspx

Before, I used Virtuemart 1.x and add more code in ECBconverter.php. So, it ok. No problem.

```
                // now write new file
                file_put_contents( $archivefile_name, $contents );
            }


          //code get exchange rate from vietcombank
            $Link = new SimpleXMLElement('http://www.vietcombank.com.vn/ExchangeRates/ExrateXML.aspx',NULL,true);
            foreach($Link->Exrate as $Exrate)
            {
            if ($Exrate['CurrencyCode']=="EUR") $tigia = $Exrate['Sell'];
            }
            //Add exchange rate VND-EUR into xml file
            $contents = str_replace ("<Cube currency='USD'", " <Cube currency='EUR' rate='1'/><Cube currency='VND' rate='".$tigia."'/> <Cube currency='USD'", $contents);



            /* XML Parsing */
```

But, now using Virtuemart 2.x.
I add this code into ECBconverter.php
It doesn't work ! I don't know why ?

```
           // now write new file
           file_put_contents( $archivefile_name, $contents );
        }


    //code get exchange rate from vietcombank
            $Link = new SimpleXMLElement('http://www.vietcombank.com.vn/ExchangeRates/ExrateXML.aspx',NULL,true);
            foreach($Link->Exrate as $Exrate)
            {
            if ($Exrate['CurrencyCode']=="EUR") $tigia = $Exrate['Sell'];
            }
            //Add exchange rate VND-EUR into xml file
            $contents = str_replace ("<Cube currency='USD'", " <Cube currency='EUR' rate='1'/><Cube Currency='VND' rate='".$tigia."'/> <Cube currency='USD'", $contents);




        /* XML Parsing */
```

Somebody help me :( I very very need your helps !
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The following relates to Virtuemart2.

In most cases you would simply convert to the default shop currency and just let Virtuemart handle it from there. Virtuemart will convert and display shop currencies as per the users selected currency.

Do so as follows:

**If you know the currency_code ...**

```
    $amount_in_shop_currency = convertToShopCurrency($amount_in_AUD, 'AUD');

    function convertToShopCurrency($amount, $currency_code)
    {
            if (!$currency_code)
                    return $amount;
            $dbo = JFactory::getDBO();
            $dbo->setQuery("SELECT virtuemart_currency_id FROM #__virtuemart_currencies WHERE currency_code_3 = '{$currency_code}' LIMIT 1");
            $currency_id = $dbo->loadResult();
            if (!$currency_id)
                    return $amount;
            if (!class_exists('CurrencyDisplay'))
                    require(JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'currencydisplay.php');
            $currency = CurrencyDisplay::getInstance();
            return $currency->convertCurrencyTo($currency_id, $amount);
    }
```

**... or if you already know the currency id ...**

```
            if (!class_exists('CurrencyDisplay'))
                    require(JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'currencydisplay.php');
            $currency = CurrencyDisplay::getInstance();
            $amount_in_shop_currency =  $currency->convertCurrencyTo($convert_from_currency_id, $convert_from_amount);
```